# next.js & next-auth When I send http request in getServerSideProps, getSession returns null in secured API Route

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to secure the API Route and this API route is called in the Client and Server-side on different pages.

On the `test` page, it returns `401 error`.

On the `test2` page, it returns the content well.

I guess it doesn't pass `session` when I send the http request in the `getServerSideProps`.

My question is, how do I secure the API routes used on the client and server-side?

/pages/test

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const Test = (props) => {
    return <div>test</div>;
};
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    // it returns session data
    const session = await getSession(context);

    // it returns error
    const res = await axios.get('/api/secret');
    return {
        props: {
            session,
            secret: res.data,
        },
    };
};
export default Test;
```

/pages/test2

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useSession, getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const Test = (props) => {
    const { data: session } = useSession();

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get('/api/secret');
            console.log(res.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [session]);

    return <div>test</div>;
};

export default Test;
```

/pages/api/secret

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const handler = (req, res) => {
    const { method } = req;
    switch (method) {
        case 'GET':
            return getSomething(req, res);
        default:
            return res.status(405).json('Method not allowed');
    }
};
const getSomething = async (req, res) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    console.log(session);
    if (session) {
        res.send({
            content: 'Welcome to the secret page',
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401).send({
            err: 'You need to be signed in.',
        });
    }
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem specifically, but your API route handler needs to be `async`

Comment: @Ben Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const session = await getSession(ctx);
    const headers = ctx.req.headers;
    if (session) {
        const data = (
            await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/secret`, {
                headers: { Cookie: headers.cookie },
            })
        
        return {
            props: {
                data,
            },
        };
    } else {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/login',
                permanent: false,
            },
        };
    }
};
```

/pages/api/secret

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';

const handler = async (req, res) => {
    const { method } = req;
    switch (method) {
        case 'GET':
            return await getSomething(req, res);
        default:
            return res.status(405).json('Method not allowed');
    }
};
const getSomething = async (req, res) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    // console.log(session);
    if (session) {
        res.send({
            content: 'Welcome to the secret page',
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401).send({
            err: 'You need to be signed in.',
        });
    }
};

export default handler;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @brandon-han Thanks for providing your solution. I came up with the same solution locally but I'm not sure how I feel about it. Did you ever find another way to do this?

Comment: @corysimmons No. I didn't find any other solutions. Do you think this is not the correct way?

Comment: Hey @BrandonHan I left a comment on the related Github discussion and will drop the link here for anyone who stumbles upon this: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4675#discussioncomment-2902281

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific method to handle request from serverSideProps, better than using useSession (which is meant for client requests)

https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#server-side

Best use `unstable_getServerSession` as mentioned in the documentation example

```
await unstable_getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
```

with the authOptions coming as an export from your [...nextauth].js